# ShowViewModel in Start() method

Tags: c#, mvvmcross, windows-phone-8.1

I use Mvvmcross for my universal application (Windows 8.1, Windows phone 8.1).
And i have an issue here:

```
//Code in Portable Class Library (Core) for wpf, windows 8.1, windows phone 8.1 

public async override void Start()
{
  ShowViewModel<TasklistViewModel>();
}
```

In Windows phone, it do not turn to a new page, without any error messades in debug. 
In Windows 8.1 all works.

It works, if i have a button-command and click myself.

```
//Code in Portable Class Library (Core) for wpf, windows 8.1, windows phone 8.1 

private MvxCommand _showTasklistViewCommand;

public MvxCommand ShowTasklistViewCommand
{
    get
    {
        _showTasklistViewCommand = _showTasklistViewCommand ?? new MvxCommand(async () => await DoShowTasklistViewCommand());
        return _showTasklistViewCommand;
    }
}

private async Task DoShowTasklistViewCommand()
{
    ShowViewModel<TasklistViewModel>();
}
```

I need to run ShowViewModel without user's click.

---

Added

1) I need do this in my View?

```
public new FirstViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return (FirstViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
    set { base.ViewModel = value; }
}

public FirstView()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += async (o, args) => await FirstView_Loaded(o, args);
}

async Task FirstView_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ViewModel.DoShowTasklistViewCommand();
}
```

2) There i need do initialize my trigers(on, off), show/unshow buttons from my settings(they load from dics or internet). I dont do it in Start(), i need do it as shown above?

3) There i can read about it?

Comment: Is there a different event that you can subscribe to, instead of the click?

Comment: I think, must be way to do it in Porable Class Library. I need more knowledge about Star() method

Comment: Start is called synchronously during navigation (OnNavigatedTo, ViewDidLoad, OnCreate, etc) - requesting a new navigation during the existing navigation is likely to cause issues - as you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks! @Stuart. I add some qustions in my question. Can help me to understad this article.